# How to determine between two c++ types without instantiating the types?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I have following problem:

I want to determine between two types without actually evaluating the 'resulting' types - since the type may not exist at all - be invalid. (Please no C++11 stuff)

Example:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <iterator>

template <bool B, typename T, typename F>
struct TemplateIf {
};

template <typename T, typename F>
struct TemplateIf<true, T, F> {
   typedef T Result;
};

template <typename T, typename F>
struct TemplateIf<false, T, F> {
 typedef F Result;
};


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

// On GCC this is error as std::iterator_traits<int>::value_type doesn't exist 
typename TemplateIf<true, int, std::iterator_traits<int>::value_type >::Result a;
a = 5;

std::cout << a << std::endl;

 return 0;
}
```

Can it somehow be determined? (Assuming that chosen type is always valid, but not chosen type maybe invalid).

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is "lazy" evaluation. Also, this looks very much like a question I asked a couple hours ago. I don't know if there is any way to do it in the general case, but in this particular case a "template template" parameter might work.

Comment: What does it mean to "determine between two types"?

Comment: @jalf As is example using TemplateIf construct

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? It's almost certainly feasible using SFINAE, but you're going about it the wrong way.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Note `TemplateIf` is aka `boost::conditional` / C++11 `std::conditional`.  But as the answers have pointed out, you need to split up evaluation of the invalid type, since typing all of `std::iterator_traits<int>::value_type` in one place is always a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of passing the types directly, pass a metafunction which evaluates to the types. This metafunction can then be evaluated lazily within the if.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

template <bool B, typename T, typename F>
struct TemplateIf {};

template <typename T, typename F>
struct TemplateIf<true, T, F> {
    typedef typename T::type Result;
};

template <typename T, typename F>
struct TemplateIf<false, T, F> {
    typedef typename F::type Result;
};

template <typename T>
struct get_value_type {
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type type;
};

template <typename T>
struct identity {
    typedef T type;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    TemplateIf<true, identity<int>, get_value_type<int> >::Result a;
    a = 5;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this works. Or just instead of metafunctions also partial specialization of class works.

Comment: `typename` in `main` is actually wrong here, btw, since there are no dependent names.

Answer (score 4):

Use lazy evaluation:

```
template<class T>
using Apply = typename T::type;

template<class T>
struct identity{ using type = T; };

template<bool B, class T, class F>
struct lazy_if{ using type = Apply<T>; };

template<class T, class F>
struct lazy_if<false, T, F> : lazy_if<true, F, T>{};

template<class T>
struct lazy_iterator_value_type{
  using type = typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type;
};
```

[Live example (C++11).](http://liveworkspace.org/code/8abd647cc3dc6ba91c40e557495615d8) For C++03, a simple rewrite to get rid of the using-aliases is needed, [see here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/f6eaff084421d54a4a40c7dc50fc4c24).

Comment: @Kirill: No, see my comment next to it. Just type `typename T::type` instead of it. The same goes for `using type = ...`, just do `typedef ... type;` instead.

Comment: Maybe you apply a little bit of editing to make it real C++ 03?

Comment: @Kirill: Meh, added a link to a C++03 example.